# Jersey Custom Exception not caught by ExceptionMapper

Tags: exception, parameters, jersey, jax-rs

I am building a REST API and created some custom parameter types that apply some validation on QueryParameters and not only. Problem is I am throwing a "IllegalQueryArgumentException" but it isn't caught by a custom ExceptionMapper.

If i throw the exception from inside a controller method the exception is caught.

**SOLUTION**
I made the custom exception extend WebApplicationException instead of RuntimeException

```
@Provider
public class CustomHandler implements ExceptionMapper<IllegalQueryArgumentException> {

    Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalQueryArgumentException e) {
        return Response.accepted("HELLO").build();
    }
}
```

config

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.epaas.eshop.api.v1;com.epaas.eshop.api.v1.jersey;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>com.epaas.eshop.api.v1.jersey.CustomHandler</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Abstract param

```
public abstract class AbstractQueryParameter<V> {

private final V value;
private final String originalParameter;

public AbstractQueryParameter(String param) throws InvalidQueryArgumentException {
        this.originalParameter = param;
        this.value = parse(param);
}

public V getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String getOriginalParameter() {
    return originalParameter;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value.toString();
}

protected abstract V parse(String param) throws InvalidQueryArgumentException;
```

}

Custom parameter class

```
public class IdParam extends AbstractQueryParameter<Long> {

public IdParam(String param) {
    super(param);
}

@Override
protected Long parse(String param) {
    try {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(param);
        if(id < 1) throw new Throwable("Id is under 1");
        return Long.parseLong(param);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw new InvalidQueryArgumentException("parameter should be an integer", throwable);
    }
}
}
```

The parse method is automaticly called when Jersey tries to bind the String parameter to the IdParam type.
Route method..

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@GET
public CollectionResource getAll(
        @Context UriInfo info,
        @QueryParam("expand") @DefaultValue("false") BooleanParam expand,
        @QueryParam("city") IdParam city,
        @QueryParam("account") IdParam account,
        @QueryParam("zipCode") ZipCodeParam zipCode,
        @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue(Pagination.DEFAULT_LIMIT) LimitParam limit,
        @QueryParam("offset") @DefaultValue(Pagination.DEFAULT_OFFSET) OffsetParam offset) {
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you haven't configure the handler, either explicitly or through package scanning. Can you should your application configuration?

Comment: i added config in web.xml

Comment: Have you done any logging to see if the handler is actually called?

Comment: the handler is called if i throw the error from inside a controller method but not inside a custom parameter parsing method

Comment: I don't know what a custom parameter parsing method is in this context. When is it called? Please post a more complete example. You method is just floating by itself with no context to go with it

Comment: i have added more context

Comment: Yeah that's pretty weird. Not sure why this happens. Doesn't say much in the spec regarding this scenario. It's weird that it works when you throw a JAX-RS exception. The only way so far I have been able to make it work is by making your exception class extend `WebApplicationException`. I original was just trying with `RuntimeException`

Comment: I remember switching between those two superclasses and not working in either case. But, I just made my exception extend WebApplicationException and it's getting caught. Thank you!